# Reprojecting NASA MODIS LST Data from ESRI:54008 to EPSG:4326 with RasterIO

Tags: qgis, python, rasterio, modis

Let me preface by saying I'm a bit new to GIS. I'm doing some exploration of MODIS Land Surface Temperature data (MOD11) that is supplied by NASA and trying to become more proficient with Geospatial Data practices in the process.

---

## Overview:

I have an HDF file, **MOD11A2.A2000057.h08v05.006.2015057173338.hdf**, from which I've extracted the the Land Surface Temperature (LST) sub-dataset using a script associated with the PyModis tool (modis_convert.py). The following command extracts the LST dataset into a single-band raster called **tiff_test_lst_day_1km.tif**.

`modis_convert.py -s "( 1 0 )" -v -e 54008 -o tiff_test MOD11A2.A2000057.h08v05.006.2015057173338.hdf`

Pulling the raster into QGIS allows me to see the expected rendering under CRS ESRI:54008 (World Sinusoidal), with an extent of -11119505.1976650003343821,3335851.5592999989166856 : -10007554.6778989993035793,4447802.0790659999474883

#### QGIS Layer Rendering

[image: LST Rendering]

#### QGIS Layer Properties Showing Extent

[image: Layer Properties from QGIS]

## Problem

I'd like to convert this to a format wherein I can view/work with this raster in EPSG:4326 format. Cursory Google searches seem to point to the concept of "reprojection" for this task; everything I'm reading seems to indicate it is a common practice within GIS.

Using Python and RasterIO, I've tried using the sample code to reproject this MODIS TIFF from ESRI:54008 to EPSG:4326. Unfortunately, the following code outputs a file that doesn't seem to have any noticeable changes other than the CRS specification in the metadata i.e. the extent of the raster is still the same so even though the CRS metadata shows as EPSG:4326, the coordinates are those associated with ESRI:54008. I would assume the goal of reprojection would be to automatically adjust the extent to match the new CRS; maybe I'm wrong and that would be too easy, but I can't seem to find any more information on this. I feel like I must be missing something here.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'

input_file = "tiff_test_lst_day_1km.tif"
output_file = "tiff_test_lst_day_1km_REPROJECTED.tif"

with rasterio.open(input_file) as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

    print(kwargs)
    with rasterio.open(output_file, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Warp(reproject)' function in the QGIS Processing toolbox https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html ?

Comment: @Kasper Thanks for the link and insight! I wasn't aware of that functionality, but using that QGIS function actually worked to properly reproject the coordinate extents along with the CRS. The tool did show the equivalent gdal CLI command, but I'm still confused on why the RasterIO reprojection didn't affect the coordinates. Ultimately, I'd like to automate this kind of processing over a large number of tiles within a Python script, so an understanding of what's going wrong with the code would still be helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you seen rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html ?